# running nutch on the hadoop ，where is the nutch logs？

Tags: logging, hadoop, nutch

my nutch running on the hadoop ，I want to check the nutch running logs,
 but cannot find the output logs like the standalone nutch logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running nutch on hadoop, the logs corresponding to each mapper and reducer of each phase is generated. The location of that is `{HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/userlogs/<task id>/syslog`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Hadoop in distributed or pseudo distributed mode then you should be able to access the logs per job with the map reduce admin interface (e.g. port 50030 of the master node).

See [this link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Logging) for the location of the logs in Hadoop.